# Simulate a mobile device on PC web with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to preview a mobile page on a PC page which has an iframe to simulate a mobile device. But mobile event can't be supported in iframe such as sliding.

How to totally simulate a mobile device by iframe?

```html
<div class="preview>
  <iframe src="http://path.to.my/mobilePage.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

```css
.preview{
  width:375px;
  height:812px;
}
.preview iframe{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

P.S. CROSS MODERN BROWSERS.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Chrome has the function you wanted.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Answer (score -2):

```html
 <iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com" width="255" height="320"></iframe>
```

Check this : http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

But in the technical side: you can use `height` and `width` and the content will respond to that.

And also if you want to test your site with its mobile events, try using the built in chrome/firefox extension just press `Ctrl+Shift+M`